Why does command 'sort' behave differently for those 2 files
Those 2 sequences of lines are not sorted the same by the Linux shell command sort (gnu-coreutils 8.22 under RHEL 7.8), even though they begin with the same distinct prefixes. Why ?
$ echo "f'*.5.7
f'9.0.0
f'*.9.6
"|sort

f'*.5.7
f'9.0.0
f'*.9.6

$ echo "f'*.5
f'9.0
f'*.9
"|sort

f'*.5
f'*.9
f'9.0


quick test to preclude a suspicion I have: 1. same result when you export LANG=C before running the two commands? 2. same result when you write your three lines to text files and sort these sort < file_with_lines.txt kind of thing (or just sort file_with_lines.txt)?

Note how they're both sorted according to the numbers: 5 < 9 < 9.6. The sort rules in some locales tend to ignore punctuation characters, or have other odd sorting rules. Use LC_ALL=C if you don't want that (or LC_COLLATE in specific, I think). See also e.g.: Unexpected sort order in en_US.UTF-8 locale Why does sort say that ɛ = e?

Indeed i should have RTFM: "The locale specified by the environment affects sort order.  Set LC_ALL=C to get the traditional sort order that uses native byte values." -  setting "export LC_ALL=C" before each command restores the traditional byte order.

Solution provided by @MarcusMuller and @ilkkachu:
As explained by the manpage:

***  WARNING  *** The locale specified by the environment affects sort order.  Set LC_ALL=C to get the traditional sort order that uses native byte values.

$ export LC_ALL=C; echo "f'*.5.7
f'9.0.0
f'*.9.6
"|sort

f'*.5.7
f'*.9.6
f'9.0.0


$ export LC_ALL=C; echo "f'*.5
f'9.0
f'*.9
"|sort

f'*.5
f'*.9
f'9.0

